# Python CSV Manipulation find and replace with the data in two different CSVs

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python

I am having a huge json data from which i have scripted and got sorted and made two csv files using python script. The data is assessments data made for educational and research purpose.

Now the first csv files contains the questions Ids, question text, choiceIDs(refereed to answer options), and choice text. Their are some fields but for this particular question this is enough...

And the second csv file contains students responses, the fields to be considered in this files are, questionids, responseids.

So now i want to map the questionid from the second csv with the questionid in the first csv and then collecting all the question text and choices text and choice ids from that particular questionid in first csv and write it to a new csv file. Then i also need to map the responseid in the second csv with the choice ids in the first csv and write it to the newly created third csv.

So how can i do this using a python script

i havent wrote the script for this yet as i am struggling with logic for the same.

Comment: Please share what you tried so far.

Comment: This question is too broad.  What is your specific problem?  Have you looked at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module documentation?

Comment: @HeshamAttia they are csv files so should i upload then on google sheets and share a link will that be fine

Comment: @augurar I hhave gone through the csv documentation, actually the task is something simiar to vlookup in excel for one column but i am actually struggling with the logic to be used as i need to get the data in the next column of the search column.

Comment: You don't have to share the csv files, just share the code that you tried so far. As @augurar suggested, you should look at python's csv module and give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library, that contains all the functions you need, starting with [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'd like to see an explanation why pandas would be better suited for his specific task than the built-in csv module.

Comment: @TimPietzcker i am new to python scripting hence i cant ans

Comment: @TejasShah: I meant to direct my question to Guillaume :)